# Can I deduct state and local taxes on a 1040A form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, state-income-tax

I just finished filing my 1040A tax form when I read that I may be able to deduct state and local taxes from my federal filing. I can't tell though if there is a way to deduct this on a 1040A form or if I need to redo everything on a 1040 form.

Comment: It's Schedule A, and as @wilee pointed out - it can only be attached to the form 1040 (i.e.: the "full" version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to itemize deductions in order to deduct state and local taxes paid.

From the [instructions for form 1040A (i1040a)](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040a.pdf):

> In most cases, your federal income tax will be less if
>   you take the larger of any itemized deductions you
>   may have or the standard deduction. **To itemize deductions,
>   you must file Form 1040.**

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Better answers don't just provide links to reference materials, they quote from them. That way of the link dies the key info is still around.